# pvk2pfx.exe - can not find

Tags: visual-studio, pfx

Could tell me where to find the file pvk2pfx.exe?
It is supposed to be located in `<programfile>/Visual Studio 8/Common7/Tools/bin/pvk2pfx.exe`, but not on my machine.
I don't seem to be able to find it online either. I tried installing the SDK, but it didn't work.

Comment: This question should not have been closed because it concerns a tool used in software development. Stack Overflow's bullet point list defining what's in scope includes "software tools commonly used by programmers". A very common use of the `pvk2pfx.exe` tool is to create test certificates for development purposes - you'll see it recommended in numerous programming blogs, and also on Microsoft's own MSDN. It gets installed as part of certain SDKs. It is a software tool, so this is absolutely on topic.

Comment: Why is this off topic? This is a perfectly fine question for a lot of programmers. Where else can you ask this question? Talk about the the self-righteous moderators... Anyway - in my case the location of pvk2pfx.exe was in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64`

Comment: mine was in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17134.0\x86`

Comment: Obviously this file can be in various places depending on your machine, operating system, installed SDKs, etc. The best approach here IMO is to use a directory scanner and search for `pvk2pfx.exe`. Treesize Viewer is a good one that found this file in literally 2 seconds for me. Here is a link: https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/

Comment: In 2021, I was able to find the file at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x86 after installing the latest Windows Software Development Kit for Windows 10, making sure to choose "Windows SDK for Desktop C++ x86 apps". The grandparent directory's name will differ depending on what version of the SDK you get.

Answer (score 22):

Have you checked the SDK path? The SDK path on my machine where `pvk2pfx.exe` is located is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin>`

Comment: For me it was in `...\Windows\v7.1A\Bin`

Comment: Rather than hating Microsoft, I thought I'd do a bit of research. I quickly came across their documentation on how to [install the WDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk) and [where to find it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/tools-for-signing-drivers) after install. Hopefully this will be more useful than "hatred" to others looking for this information.

Comment: I apparently unchecked something essential from the SDK installer. Running it again just told me everything was up-to-date, but it did ask to download the install files (~77 different MSI files). I used an MSI explorer tool and found `pvk2pfx.exe` was located in the `Windows SDK Desktop Tools x86-x86_en-us.msi` installer. Running that copied the file to the SDK path, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x86` in my case. (I can't post this as a separate answer because the question is closed).

Comment: Rather than looking for the tool in specific folders, put Windows Search to help you by typing "pvk2pfx.exe" on the search box in C:\ directory. The tool was found in my computer at three different locations including C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\arm64 after installing winsdksetup.exe downloaded from https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/2/2/42245968-6A79-4DA7-A5FB-08C0AD0AE661/windowssdk/winsdksetup.exe

Comment: In the Windows SDK you have to specifically choose "Windows SDK for Desktop C++ x86 apps" (and its requirements). If you don't check that box, a file search won't help you.

Answer (score 6):

pvk2pfx.exe is not related to Microsoft .NET (2.0) SDK but to C/C++ SDK so look fo in c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\ directory.

Comment: I found it in the Microsoft SDKs directory under v7.1A, just FYI.  From the Windows directory, do 'dir pvk*.exe /s' to find it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Windows SDK https://developer.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/ . When installing please have selected "Windows SDK for Desktop C++ x86 apps" option.

Then the pvk2pfx.exe file will be located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22000.0\x86 .

Answer (score 0):

You can also run the "Developer Powershell for VS 2022" (or the latest equivalent) and it will already know where to look.